# Filter list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists as below:

```
> str(mylist1)
List of 62
 $ :List of 9
  ..$ snp     : chr [1:463] "rs2495066" "rs2495065" "rs11803252" "rs2495014" ...
  ..$ pvalues : num [1:463] 0.733 0.729 0.89 0.779 0.779 ...
  ..$ MAF     : num [1:463] 0.982 0.982 0.906 0.904 0.903 0.903 0.902 0.924 0.904 0.239 ...
  ..$ chr     : int [1:463] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ position: int [1:463] 13982716 13982728 13984208 13985591 13988076 13988403 13989227 13989959 13990258 13990291 ...
  ..$ type    : chr "cc"
  ..$ s       : num 0.409
  ..$ N       : num 130644
  ..$ LD      : num [1:452, 1:452] 1 1 0.392 0.39 0.392 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:452] "rs2495066" "rs2495065" "rs11803252" "rs2495014" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:452] "rs2495066" "rs2495065" "rs11803252" "rs2495014" ...
```

I need to filter this list as `snp` match with the rs number in `LD` so that the length of columns `snp, pvalues, MAF, chr, position` and `LD` would be the same.

So far I have tried :

```
mylist2=Filter(function(i){mylist1[[i]]$snp %in% names(mylist1[[i]]$LD[,1])},mylist1)
```

But it is giving me error: `Error in mylist1[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Did I clarify the issue or further explanation is needed? Any help?

Best, Zillur

Actual data is large 300MB. Here is the last few elements of the list: https://github.com/zillurbmb51/Kajoli/blob/master/mylist1.txt

Hope it helps.

```
[[60]]
[[60]]$snp
 [1] "rs9611195"   "rs4820382"   "rs5757719"   "rs79439013"  "rs713689"    "rs2092168"   "rs115087727" "rs5757720"   "rs10427762" 
[10] "rs5757721"   "rs117711358" "rs117109395" "rs11089954"  "rs113358105" "rs2413597"   "rs2413598"   "rs4438587"   "rs76190836" 
[19] "rs5757723"   "rs75675695"  "rs113448717" "rs58093579"  "rs7284221"   "rs2413599"   "rs5757725"   "rs116980552" "rs5757726"  
[28] "rs61259516"  "rs9607655"   "rs143776090" "rs9611198"   "rs9607658"   "rs6001621"   "rs9623017"   "rs9619819"   "rs75594549" 
[37] "rs4820383"   "rs62652622"  "rs80208362"  "rs73885269"  "rs5757727"   "rs62228477"  "rs116867091" "rs12484107"  "rs5757728"  
[46] "rs55684383"  "rs56753811"  "rs7288455"   "rs74860018"  "rs3747178"   "rs62228478"  "rs5757730"   "rs5757731"   "rs116722699"
[55] "rs5757732"   "rs78432290"  "rs5757733"   "rs116516050" "rs5750851"   "rs12484689"  "rs5750852"   "rs2413600"   "rs3788556"  
[64] "rs144587111" "rs5757734"   "rs132567"   

[[60]]$pvalues
 [1] 2.032e-04 5.642e-01 2.930e-08 5.871e-01 6.189e-04 2.901e-08 5.647e-01 1.199e-02 3.399e-04 1.861e-08 4.642e-02 6.906e-01 2.782e-04
[14] 6.031e-01 1.105e-02 5.572e-01 2.222e-03 5.410e-01 1.640e-02 1.593e-02 5.414e-01 1.592e-02 1.547e-02 2.013e-02 1.537e-03 3.861e-01
[27] 2.073e-03 1.992e-03 1.455e-01 1.069e-02 3.940e-09 2.479e-09 1.802e-01 1.080e-05 1.256e-05 3.018e-02 1.373e-08 1.648e-04 2.347e-03
[40] 2.592e-03 1.356e-08 3.306e-09 2.514e-03 2.428e-03 8.093e-05 2.663e-03 1.528e-03 8.192e-09 4.851e-01 1.309e-04 4.743e-01 1.925e-10
[53] 1.029e-09 3.361e-01 6.014e-05 3.547e-01 2.610e-09 3.576e-01 2.233e-09 3.283e-03 2.924e-05 2.043e-08 4.428e-09 4.465e-01 1.393e-03
[66] 9.248e-04

[[60]]$MAF
 [1] 0.682 0.943 0.405 0.943 0.681 0.406 0.943 0.725 0.682 0.405 0.987 0.986 0.682 0.943 0.724 0.942 0.782 0.943 0.725 0.725 0.942 0.725
[23] 0.725 0.725 0.623 0.978 0.783 0.782 0.764 0.986 0.461 0.464 0.892 0.191 0.748 0.952 0.404 0.676 0.785 0.787 0.405 0.452 0.983 0.785
[45] 0.680 0.786 0.781 0.401 0.970 0.680 0.985 0.462 0.460 0.957 0.677 0.944 0.458 0.944 0.457 0.785 0.675 0.398 0.470 0.955 0.736 0.270

[[60]]$chr
 [1] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22
[46] 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 22

[[60]]$position
 [1] 39944485 39944789 39945791 39945823 39946280 39947068 39947167 39947259 39947439 39947574 39948027 39948533 39949430 39949757 39949792
[16] 39950172 39950349 39950747 39950805 39951106 39951182 39951409 39951658 39952098 39952275 39952328 39952633 39953234 39953569 39955480
[31] 39955873 39957740 39957762 39959057 39960115 39961097 39961286 39961829 39962380 39963092 39963173 39963426 39964114 39964503 39965471
[46] 39965699 39966094 39966547 39966686 39966856 39967082 39967430 39967785 39967880 39968018 39968140 39968173 39968269 39969767 39969895
[61] 39972069 39972075 39972162 39973113 39973151 39973526

[[60]]$type
[1] "cc"

[[60]]$s
[1] 0.4086372

[[60]]$N
[1] 130644

[[60]]$LD
             rs9611195  rs4820382  rs5757719 rs79439013   rs713689  rs2092168 rs115087727  rs5757720 rs10427762 rs5757721 rs113358105
rs9611195    1.0000000 -0.1596060  0.5866870 -0.1596060  0.9938410  0.5888050  -0.1654670 -0.4723010  0.9979330  0.584849  -0.1654670
rs4820382   -0.1596060  1.0000000  0.1913190  1.0000000 -0.1622850  0.1905150   0.9734350  0.3856250 -0.1607200  0.187671   0.9734350
rs5757719    0.5866870  0.1913190  1.0000000  0.1913190  0.5785180  0.9914480   0.1639770  0.4273840  0.5861640  0.989386   0.1639770
rs79439013  -0.1596060  1.0000000  0.1913190  1.0000000 -0.1622850  0.1905150   0.9734350  0.3856250 -0.1607200  0.187671   0.9734350
rs713689     0.9938410 -0.1622850  0.5785180 -0.1622850  1.0000000  0.5805360  -0.1682270 -0.4744540  0.9958850  0.584957  -0.1682270
rs2092168    0.5888050  0.1905150  0.9914480  0.1905150  0.5805360  1.0000000   0.1890970  0.4343510  0.5882610  0.993550   0.1890970
rs115087727 -0.1654670  0.9734350  0.1639770  0.9734350 -0.1682270  0.1890970   1.0000000  0.3906100 -0.1666170  0.186157   1.0000000
rs5757720   -0.4723010  0.3856250  0.4273840  0.3856250 -0.4744540  0.4343510   0.3906100  1.0000000 -0.4705910  0.431725   0.3906100
rs10427762   0.9979330 -0.1607200  0.5861640 -0.1607200  0.9958850  0.5882610  -0.1666170 -0.4705910  1.0000000  0.584276  -0.1666170
rs5757721    0.5848490  0.1876710  0.9893860  0.1876710  0.5849570  0.9935500   0.1861570  0.4317250  0.5842760  1.000000   0.1861570
rs113358105 -0.1654670  0.9734350  0.1639770  0.9734350 -0.1682270  0.1890970   1.0000000  0.3906100 -0.1666170  0.186157   1.0000000
rs2413597   -0.4731770  0.3826610  0.4288800  0.3826610 -0.4753420  0.4311260   0.3875870  0.9974590 -0.4714870  0.433179   0.3875870
rs2413598   -0.1654670  0.9734350  0.1639770  0.9734350 -0.1682270  0.1890970   1.0000000  0.3906100 -0.1666170  0.186157   1.0000000
rs4438587   -0.4104950 -0.1506830  0.3632000 -0.1506830 -0.4112040  0.3561120  -0.1607350  0.8458020 -0.4079960  0.355000  -0.1607350
rs76190836  -0.1654670  0.9734350  0.1639770  0.9734350 -0.1682270  0.1890970   1.0000000  0.3906100 -0.1666170  0.186157   1.0000000
rs5757723   -0.4723010  0.3856250  0.4273840  0.3856250 -0.4744540  0.4343510   0.3906100  1.0000000 -0.4705910  0.431725   0.3906100
             rs2413597  rs2413598  rs4438587 rs76190836  rs5757723 rs75675695 rs113448717 rs58093579  rs7284221  rs2413599  rs5757725
rs9611195   -0.4731770 -0.1654670 -0.4104950 -0.1654670 -0.4723010 -0.4723010  -0.1617440 -0.4723010 -0.4723010 -0.4723010  0.8816180
rs4820382    0.3826610  0.9734350 -0.1506830  0.9734350  0.3856250  0.3856250   0.9649750  0.3856250  0.3856250  0.3856250  0.2968180
rs5757719    0.4288800  0.1639770  0.3632000  0.1639770  0.4273840  0.4273840   0.1694800  0.4273840  0.4273840  0.4273840  0.6370020
rs79439013   0.3826610  0.9734350 -0.1506830  0.9734350  0.3856250  0.3856250   0.9649750  0.3856250  0.3856250  0.3856250  0.2968180
rs713689    -0.4753420 -0.1682270 -0.4112040 -0.1682270 -0.4744540 -0.4744540  -0.1645410 -0.4744540 -0.4744540 -0.4744540  0.8822650
rs2092168    0.4311260  0.1890970  0.3561120  0.1890970  0.4343510  0.4343510   0.1944420  0.4343510  0.4343510  0.4343510  0.6466010
rs115087727  0.3875870  1.0000000 -0.1607350  1.0000000  0.3906100  0.3906100   0.9913010  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3034560
rs5757720    0.9974590  0.3906100  0.8458020  0.3906100  1.0000000  1.0000000   0.3922890  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000 -0.2773470
rs10427762  -0.4714870 -0.1666170 -0.4079960 -0.1666170 -0.4705910 -0.4705910  -0.1629000 -0.4705910 -0.4705910 -0.4705910  0.8790600
rs5757721    0.4331790  0.1861570  0.3550000  0.1861570  0.4317250  0.4317250   0.1914760  0.4317250  0.4317250  0.4317250  0.6535360
rs113358105  0.3875870  1.0000000 -0.1607350  1.0000000  0.3906100  0.3906100   0.9913010  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3034560
rs2413597    1.0000000  0.3875870  0.8448300  0.3875870  0.9974590  0.9974590   0.3892470  0.9974590  0.9974590  0.9974590 -0.2751950
rs2413598    0.3875870  1.0000000 -0.1607350  1.0000000  0.3906100  0.3906100   0.9913010  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3034560
rs4438587    0.8448300 -0.1607350  1.0000000 -0.1607350  0.8458020  0.8458020  -0.1538930  0.8458020  0.8458020  0.8458020 -0.4732290
rs76190836   0.3875870  1.0000000 -0.1607350  1.0000000  0.3906100  0.3906100   0.9913010  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3906100  0.3034560
rs5757723    0.9974590  0.3906100  0.8458020  0.3906100  1.0000000  1.0000000   0.3922890  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000 -0.2773470
            rs116980552  rs5757726 rs61259516  rs9607655 rs143776090  rs9611198  rs9607658  rs6001621  rs9623017  rs9619819  rs75594549
rs9611195    -0.0938414 -0.4104950 -0.4104950  0.8319670 -0.11581300  0.6461730  0.6554380 -0.2026890  0.3667590  0.7851120  0.24221900
rs4820382    -0.0627787 -0.1506830 -0.1506830 -0.1427160 -0.06473530 -0.2796630 -0.2782520 -0.0926562  0.1253330 -0.1155360 -0.02750740
rs5757719     0.0709376  0.3632000  0.3632000  0.5053510  0.12391800  0.8826400  0.8792890 -0.4001440  0.6098530  0.4576930  0.14986200
rs79439013   -0.0627787 -0.1506830 -0.1506830 -0.1427160 -0.06473530 -0.2796630 -0.2782520 -0.0926562  0.1253330 -0.1155360 -0.02750740
rs713689     -0.0952452 -0.4112040 -0.4112040  0.8363780 -0.11722700  0.6475920  0.6488550 -0.2064430  0.3664200  0.7902890  0.23904000
rs2092168     0.0703184  0.3561120  0.3561120  0.5080880  0.10900400  0.8745400  0.8714100 -0.4054870  0.6065900  0.4604800  0.14893100
rs115087727  -0.0647308 -0.1607350 -0.1607350 -0.1457300 -0.06674830 -0.2941710 -0.2922260 -0.0992430  0.1122840 -0.1181550 -0.03264060
rs5757720     0.1812600  0.8458020  0.8458020 -0.3730670  0.24793300  0.2336040  0.2198650 -0.2163130  0.2527800 -0.3727690 -0.10751800
rs10427762   -0.0944393 -0.4079960 -0.4079960  0.8302050 -0.11644400  0.6461600  0.6555010 -0.2042220  0.3689450  0.7834300  0.24148900
rs5757721     0.0687810  0.3550000  0.3550000  0.5145850  0.12206600  0.8822100  0.8708610 -0.4100900  0.6074870  0.4676330  0.14625000
rs113358105  -0.0647308 -0.1607350 -0.1607350 -0.1457300 -0.06674830 -0.2941710 -0.2922260 -0.0992430  0.1122840 -0.1181550 -0.03264060
rs2413597     0.1798010  0.8448300  0.8448300 -0.3739390  0.26197400  0.2364580  0.2228260 -0.2167850  0.2536560 -0.3735130 -0.10801800
rs2413598    -0.0647308 -0.1607350 -0.1607350 -0.1457300 -0.06674830 -0.2941710 -0.2922260 -0.0992430  0.1122840 -0.1181550 -0.03264060
rs4438587     0.2318570  1.0000000  1.0000000 -0.3155380  0.30451000  0.4209470  0.4050890 -0.1744110  0.2059510 -0.3311990 -0.09636130
rs76190836   -0.0647308 -0.1607350 -0.1607350 -0.1457300 -0.06674830 -0.2941710 -0.2922260 -0.0992430  0.1122840 -0.1181550 -0.03264060
rs5757723     0.1812600  0.8458020  0.8458020 -0.3730670  0.24793300  0.2336040  0.2198650 -0.2163130  0.2527800 -0.3727690 -0.10751800
             rs4820383 rs62652622 rs80208362 rs73885269  rs5757727 rs62228477 rs12484107  rs5757728 rs55684383 rs56753811  rs7288455
rs9611195    0.5869280  0.9817220 -0.3999290 -0.3966800  0.5862760  0.6288670 -0.3999290  0.9896660 -0.3952140 -0.4038560  0.5657670
rs4820382    0.1884830 -0.1654090 -0.1470980 -0.1459790  0.1896970 -0.2720380 -0.1470980 -0.1584950 -0.1453640 -0.1361690  0.1974320
rs5757719    0.9893600  0.5842810  0.3606470  0.3620060  0.9914660  0.8558610  0.3606470  0.5788150  0.3563950  0.3251820  0.9599060
rs79439013   0.1884830 -0.1654090 -0.1470980 -0.1459790  0.1896970 -0.2720380 -0.1470980 -0.1584950 -0.1453640 -0.1361690  0.1974320
rs713689     0.5786770  0.9836610 -0.4005480 -0.3972760  0.5780440  0.6300370 -0.4005480  0.9835530 -0.3958260 -0.3950260  0.5657070
rs2092168    0.9935710  0.5820760  0.3535500  0.3549340  0.9957060  0.8474630  0.3535500  0.5809010  0.3493820  0.3178460  0.9637450
rs115087727  0.1870400 -0.1714450 -0.1570800 -0.1559280  0.1882850 -0.2871760 -0.1570800 -0.1643210 -0.1552280 -0.1467520  0.1953010
rs5757720    0.4294320 -0.4592700  0.8312330  0.8291230  0.4324860  0.2233610  0.8312330 -0.4694030  0.8214340  0.7966740  0.4204870
rs10427762   0.5863790  0.9796030 -0.3973600 -0.3940970  0.5857340  0.6287520 -0.3973600  0.9876010 -0.3926750 -0.4014590  0.5651110
rs5757721    0.9914320  0.5905840  0.3525460  0.3539610  0.9935910  0.8548040  0.3525460  0.5769660  0.3483900  0.3264830  0.9699600
rs113358105  0.1870400 -0.1714450 -0.1570800 -0.1559280  0.1882850 -0.2871760 -0.1570800 -0.1643210 -0.1552280 -0.1467520  0.1953010
rs2413597    0.4308920 -0.4556920  0.8304000  0.8283120  0.4339450  0.2261500  0.8304000 -0.4702820  0.8206100  0.7958210  0.4219210
rs2413598    0.1870400 -0.1714450 -0.1570800 -0.1559280  0.1882850 -0.2871760 -0.1570800 -0.1643210 -0.1552280 -0.1467520  0.1953010
rs4438587    0.3520290 -0.3930590  0.9822610  0.9793310  0.3545830  0.4059120  0.9822610 -0.4080530  0.9706810  0.9392220  0.3376520
rs76190836   0.1870400 -0.1714450 -0.1570800 -0.1559280  0.1882850 -0.2871760 -0.1570800 -0.1643210 -0.1552280 -0.1467520  0.1953010
rs5757723    0.4294320 -0.4592700  0.8312330  0.8291230  0.4324860  0.2233610  0.8312330 -0.4694030  0.8214340  0.7966740  0.4204870
            rs74860018  rs3747178 rs62228478  rs5757730  rs5757731 rs116722699  rs5757732 rs78432290  rs5757733 rs116516050  rs5750851
rs9611195   -0.1368940  0.9875710 -0.0507672  0.6299090  0.6417950  -0.1017350  0.9774440 -0.1644570  0.6360090  -0.1644570  0.6360090
rs4820382   -0.0591150 -0.1580400 -0.0514570 -0.2585690 -0.2657340   0.8049810 -0.1464990  0.9545260 -0.2702720   0.9545260 -0.2702720
rs5757719    0.1184060  0.5775450 -0.1111420  0.8494210  0.8561300   0.1553170  0.5876730  0.1615680  0.8625270   0.1615680  0.8625270
rs79439013  -0.0591150 -0.1580400 -0.0514570 -0.2585690 -0.2657340   0.8049810 -0.1464990  0.9545260 -0.2702720   0.9545260 -0.2702720
rs713689    -0.1387470  0.9814720 -0.0519634  0.6313530  0.6431190  -0.1039110  0.9712210 -0.1671570  0.6372500  -0.1671570  0.6372500
rs2092168    0.1177310  0.5796340 -0.1127240  0.8412730  0.8478230   0.1546970  0.5897200  0.1870740  0.8541610   0.1870740  0.8541610
rs115087727 -0.0622233 -0.1638550 -0.0530570 -0.2732430 -0.2806900   0.7836520 -0.1528430  0.9823300 -0.2853840   0.9823300 -0.2853840
rs5757720    0.2809420 -0.4684510 -0.0663519  0.2154510  0.2093470   0.2820730 -0.4461670  0.3872770  0.2227070   0.3872770  0.2227070
rs10427762  -0.1377010  0.9855040 -0.0512366  0.6298960  0.6417470  -0.1026020  0.9753310 -0.1655850  0.6359220  -0.1655850  0.6359220
rs5757721    0.1157030  0.5757080 -0.1141490  0.8488630  0.8553530   0.1524360  0.5856590  0.1841950  0.8616130   0.1841950  0.8616130
rs113358105 -0.0622233 -0.1638550 -0.0530570 -0.2732430 -0.2806900   0.7836520 -0.1528430  0.9823300 -0.2853840   0.9823300 -0.2853840
rs2413597    0.2788060 -0.4693360 -0.0665058  0.2183600  0.2122750   0.2798340 -0.4472020  0.3842930  0.2255430   0.3842930  0.2255430
rs2413598   -0.0622233 -0.1638550 -0.0530570 -0.2732430 -0.2806900   0.7836520 -0.1528430  0.9823300 -0.2853840   0.9823300 -0.2853840
rs4438587    0.3372800 -0.4073020 -0.0403923  0.3893550  0.3871260  -0.1517230 -0.3897910 -0.1540670  0.4041720  -0.1540670  0.4041720
rs76190836  -0.0622233 -0.1638550 -0.0530570 -0.2732430 -0.2806900   0.7836520 -0.1528430  0.9823300 -0.2853840   0.9823300 -0.2853840
rs5757723    0.2809420 -0.4684510 -0.0663519  0.2154510  0.2093470   0.2820730 -0.4461670  0.3872770  0.2227070   0.3872770  0.2227070
            rs12484689  rs5750852  rs2413600  rs3788556 rs144587111  rs5757734   rs132567
rs9611195   -0.3972160  0.9652770  0.5562330  0.6474040  -0.1094420 -0.1910440 -0.7727030
rs4820382   -0.1425180 -0.1481030  0.1793730 -0.2141650   0.7242020 -0.1130070  0.1058070
rs5757719    0.3204120  0.5801060  0.9376240  0.8276260   0.1305660  0.2898970 -0.4935320
rs79439013  -0.1425180 -0.1481030  0.1793730 -0.2141650   0.7242020 -0.1130070  0.1058070
rs713689    -0.3881400  0.9590360  0.5559630  0.6488360  -0.1116370 -0.1935320 -0.7763350
rs2092168    0.3130200  0.5778750  0.9411670  0.8193890   0.1297670  0.2771950 -0.5000600
rs115087727 -0.1528480 -0.1544920  0.1771430 -0.2296480   0.7044590 -0.1260670  0.1021570
rs5757720    0.7840110 -0.4455250  0.4064900  0.1720890   0.2634750  0.5151850  0.3157780
rs10427762  -0.3947280  0.9631450  0.5554940  0.6474150  -0.1103250 -0.1890480 -0.7707100
rs5757721    0.3219150  0.5779680  0.9471260  0.8269660   0.1274490  0.2793100 -0.5056450
rs113358105 -0.1528480 -0.1544920  0.1771430 -0.2296480   0.7044590 -0.1260670  0.1021570
rs2413597    0.7833140 -0.4420140  0.4079070  0.1752080   0.2613140  0.5202000  0.3171330
rs2413598   -0.1528480 -0.1544920  0.1771430 -0.2296480   0.7044590 -0.1260670  0.1021570
rs4438587    0.9291780 -0.3881470  0.3331680  0.3175990  -0.1257690  0.6254290  0.2793660
rs76190836  -0.1528480 -0.1544920  0.1771430 -0.2296480   0.7044590 -0.1260670  0.1021570
rs5757723    0.7840110 -0.4455250  0.4064900  0.1720890   0.2634750  0.5151850  0.3157780
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 46 rows ]
```

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example so that answerers can work through the problem on their own machines. The error you're getting means that `i` is a list, rather than an integer. So you're doing something like `mylist[[list(2)]]` - that code will give you the same error.

Comment: Please subset the relevant indices of the data and reproduce with 'dput()`.

Comment: Try: `lapply(mylist1, function(x){ if (length x > 30) x[1:30]; else x} ) |> dput()`

Comment: @CaptainHat, Getting error: `Error: unexpected symbol in "lapply(mylist1, function(x){ if (length x"`
for the above command.

Comment: sorry, should be `length(x) > 30`

Comment: Thanks @CaptainHat, I have tried it already and getting: `Error: unexpected 'else' in "lapply(mylist1, function(x){ if (length(x) > 30) x[1:30]; else"`

Comment: @CaptainHat, The error less command is: `lapply(mylist1, function(x){ if (length(x) > 30) x[1:30] else x} ) |> dput()` But it still give me the whole lists not the first 30 elements.

Answer (score 0):

As the length of nested lists are different, I had to do a for loop for each nested lists. Here is the code which resolved the issue.

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist1)){mylist1[[i]]$pvalues=mylist1[[i]]$pvalues[mylist1[[i]]$snp %in% names(mylist1[[i]]$LD[,1])]}
for (i in 1:length(mylist1)){mylist1[[i]]$MAF=mylist1[[i]]$MAFp[mylist1[[i]]$snp %in% names(mylist1[[i]]$LD[,1])]}
for (i in 1:length(mylist1)){mylist1[[i]]$chr=mylist1[[i]]$chr[mylist1[[i]]$snp %in% names(mylist1[[i]]$LD[,1])]}
for (i in 1:length(mylist1)){mylist1[[i]]$position=mylist1[[i]]$position[mylist1[[i]]$snp %in% names(mylist1[[i]]$LD[,1])]}
for (i in 1:length(mylist1)){mylist1[[i]]$snp=mylist1[[i]]$snp[mylist1[[i]]$snp %in% names(mylist1[[i]]$LD[,1])]}
```

Maybe there are better/easier alternatives but my knowledge is limited. The good thing is that it works and give expected outputs.